# How do I remove the query-string from my URL redirect

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, query-string

So i made this script below so that someone can enter an order ID and it would redirect to the following http://domain.tld/order/254441.

but it give me a query-string of ?webid=254441 at the end the URL. How do I remove this?

```js
  function urlRedirect(){
    var action_src = "/orders/" + document.getElementsByName("webid")[0].value;
    var form_url = document.getElementById('form_url');
    form_url.action = action_src ;
}
```

```html
<p>Search by ID</p>

<form id="form_url" onsubmit="urlRedirect()"><input name="webid" type="text" /> <input type="submit" value="Search" /></form>
```

And if anyone has suggestions on making the code better that would be great! :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `method` of your form to `"POST"`.

```
<form id="form_url" onsubmit="urlRedirect()" method="POST">
```

HTTP POST requests supply additional data from the client (browser) to the server in the message body. In contrast, GET requests include all required data in the URL. When the method is GET, all form data is encoded into the URL, appended to the action URL as query string parameters. With POST, form data appears within the message body of the HTTP request.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method).